# React Native FlatList only renders 10 items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to display a FlatList with a dataset of 86 items and it's only displaying 10 and will not load more.

I tried messing with the container size through styles but no avail.

```
return (
  <View>
    <Text>{this.state.cards.length}</Text>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.cards}
      renderItem={(theInfo) => <CardImage key={theInfo.key} info={theInfo}/>}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.toString()}
    />
  </View>
);
```

I expect this to display 86 items (this.state.cards.length displays 86), the application only displays 10 and will not load more.

Edit: rn version 0.57.8

Comment: If I'm not wrong `keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.toString()}` is getting `object` as first param(`item`) and `item.toString()` will be `'[object Object]'`. Try removing `keyExtractor` prop since you are already adding `key` prop in `renderItem`

Comment: @RamKrish2079 ```kyeExtractor``` seems ok, see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-listview

Comment: react-native version?

Comment: @SantoshSharma 0.57.8, I edited the post

Comment: Change View to ScrollView

Comment: If you change the `View` to `ScrollView`, it'll work but you'll lose the `FlatList`'s ability to optimize the rendering (and be stuck with yellow warnings). It looks like all that's missing is an `item` attribute for your `CardImage` element, see my answer below for the example

Answer (score 16):

You should set following property

```
initialNumToRender={50}
```

As the default is 10

Source: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#initialnumtorender

Comment: Can you add the source to this?

Comment: Source Added. @Mukeyii

Comment: There is no default value given in the documentation as far as I can see. And also I don't think that rendering 50 rows in the initial batch is good for performance.

Comment: I did this but now it's only displaying 50. Still won't load more. Ideally I'd like to initially render 10 then load the rest as needed.

Comment: @Mukeyii Here you can find the default value as 10
https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and makes the virtualization capability of the FlatList totally useless...

Answer (score 2):

The issue appeared after updating React Native from version 62 to 64. My solution was to hide the FlatList when there are not elements to show.

```
return (
  <View>
   <Text>{this.state.cards.length}</Text>
   {this.state.cards.length > 0 &&
   <FlatList
     data={this.state.cards}
     renderItem={(theInfo) => <CardImage key={theInfo.key} info={theInfo}/>}
     keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.toString()}
   />
   }
  </View>
);
```

Also [Arjun Jain's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56050994/2860309) solution fixes the issue.

Comment: perfect! this is right answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using initialNumToRender is not a proper solution for this. It affects the processing as the whole list is rendered by `flatList`.
If you're using animation anywhere in your project then you can add `isInteraction: false` parameter in `Animated.timing()`
eg-

```
Animated.timing(
    this.spinValue,
    {
      toValue: -1,
      duration: 4000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      isInteraction: false
    }
  ).start( ()=> this.spin() )
```

for more information, you can see [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15990#issuecomment-469268244) comment in react-native project's issues.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: how is this relevant??

Answer (score 0):

Change View to ScrollView

Updated Code:

```
return (
  <ScrollView>
    <Text>{this.state.cards.length}</Text>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.cards}
      renderItem={(theInfo) => <CardImage key={theInfo.key} info={theInfo}/>}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.toString()}
    />
  </ScrollView>
);
```

Comment: Doing so will take away all the goodness of Flatlist.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem, the only thing that worked from amongst these answers was [Arjun Jain's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56050994/2860309) but the moment you do that the `FlatList` can no longer determine the correct number of items to render and ceases to be efficient (and in my case, the list of items is 2000+ entries so this matters).

After loads of fiddling, what turned out to be missing in my code was that the rendered element (in this case, `CardImage`, in mine it was a `ListItem`) just needs an `item` attribute:

```
return (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <Text>{this.state.cards.length}</Text>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.cards}
      renderItem={(theInfo) => <CardImage item={theInfo} key={theInfo.key} info={theInfo}/>}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.toString()}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem in a different way, maybe it helps someone...

For me, setting `initialNumToRender={50}` didn't solv all the problems, it caused another problem.

To fix it, in my case I had:

```js
    renderItem({ item }) {
    return <MyButton 
      key={String(item._id)}
      ... other props
    />
```

At the style of MyButton, I had as the container style:

```css
flex: 1
height: 68px;
padding-right: 10px;
margin-top: 15px;
flex-direction: row;
```

So I changed it to:

```css
height: 68px;
padding-right: 10px;
margin-top: 15px;
flex-direction: row;
```

and its fixed!! `flex: 1`, was causing the FlatList to render empty spaces for fields that was not rendered... Weird!